# Assumptions of compound Poisson model

Tags: poisson-distribution, independence, joint-distribution, poisson-process, compound-distributions

My understanding of a [compound Poisson RV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_Poisson_distribution) is one defined as

$$Y=\sum_{n=1}^N X_n$$

where

1. $\{X_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of identically distributed and mutually independent (iid) RVs
2. $N$ is a Poisson RV
3. $N$ is independent of $\{X_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}.$

I want to check if my statement of assumption 3 is correct.

In particular, does assumption 3 mean that $N$ is independent of $(X_{n_1},X_{n_2},...,X_{n_k})'$ for every finite subset $\{n_1,...,n_k\}\subseteq \mathbb{N}$?

I don't think assumptions 1 and 2, and $X_n$ and $N$ being *pairwise* independent (for each $n$) are enough to obtain the variance listed in the wiki article, at least from what I worked out. Let me know if you agree.